# How do you change the CakePHP model validation redirect?

Tags: validation, cakephp, redirect

CakePHP seems to redirect an invalid form back to the controller/action the form was sent from.  But in my case, the form comes from controller/action/value and I need to validation redirect to go there.

I've tried adding redirects in my controller in the appropriate place to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: cake doesnt redirect on invalid forms - at least not using the "appropriate cake way". that would destroy the whole concept of persistent forms (redirecting would lose the previously entered data)

Comment: Hi Ryan, have you found a way to keep the validation data upon redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You totally can do this. Just manually check the validation from the controller like this:

```
if ($this->ModelName->validates(array('fieldList' => array('field1', 'field2')))) {
    // valid - do save here and continue
} else {
    // invalid - do redirect here
}
```

You can read more here:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller